# Deploy with docker swarm on homogeneous devices without cluster

Tags: docker, deployment, kubernetes, docker-swarm

Is it possible to use docker swarm for deployment of docker containers on homogeneous device? The answer should be yes for clusters right. But the IOT devices are not internally connected and do not have any relation to each other beside the images.

If there is a way to do it with docker swarm (or Kubernetes), what would be the workflow? If others technologies out there, would be happy to hear a suggestions.

Comment: which device you are planning to use?

Comment: Basically RPis or other ARM based SOCs

Comment: The machines aren't related to each other? Are you creating a botnet?

Comment: No, they are also not communicating with each other. So is IOT by definition a botnet? ^^ And the machines are related, because they are setup and shipped by me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- **continuous ci** with **docker** and **gitlab** could fit your needs, since you build your images in gitlab and just deploy by cron or another method , and the devices can be "passive" (behind nat and you cannot send commands ) https://www.taniarascia.com/continuous-integration-pipeline-docker/
- since **you do not need a cluster** , one solution would be using [**Docker context**](https://docs.docker.com/engine/context/working-with-contexts/) and add their remotes as context → you need a VPN or ssh to acces the docker daemons via TCP/Socket
- if you build a **VPN**  ( Layer2 or 3 , all IP's have to "see" each other ) or make use of **public IPv4/IPv6** , then you can actually use docker swarm and also start docker services not controlled by swarm on each machine , since it has a docker socket . Also you can have each machine as a manager , and of course **you decide** which external ip/port you bind a service ( after using tags to set on which machine/machine-type it is run )
- to enable ssh behind nat and deploy manually , you could use tor : https://www.howtoforge.com/anonymous-ssh-sessions-with-tor
- to prevent opening a socket , you might use ssh+local port forward or ssh+socat to forward the unix socket
- IoT is not necessarily a botnet , but many devices are just badly implemented or spyware, sending all the data to their cloud for e.g. switching a light on/off